# How to plot Acutal and predictions in python (While 0 and 1)

Tags: python, prediction

[image]

How to plot the Acutal vs Prediction graph in python. It's was 0 and 1 values so plot is not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The library matplotlib is usually used for displaying tables and graphs. It is easy to use and well-developed. Here is a link to the table-module:
https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html

Otherwise, you may use tk and tkinter, although this might be kind of an overkill for your situation.